# How to check accuracy() in VAR model and How to determine right seasonality( is there a function)

Tags: r, time-series, var, forecast

How to check `accuracy()` in VAR model and How to determine the right seasonality( is there a function)
I am trying to create a VAR model. I have monthly data

```
Var_model <- VAR(cb, p = 1, type = "both", season = 12, exog = NULL)
```

I put season=12 by default since my data is monthly. How to determine seasonality?

mstl decomposition graphics

[peca](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gVhN.png)

[waln](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJ1ol.png)

[almo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHUMw.png)

[pean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmFt9.png)

Here is the main problem. How to run `accuracy()` in var model?

```
forecast <- predict(Var_model, n.ahead = 24, ci = 0.95)
accuracy(forecast$fcst[[1]][,"fcst"], almo)
```

Here I think I am following procedure. accuracy(forecast, data) but still getting an error

> Error in testaccuracy(object, x, test, d, D) : Not enough forecasts.
> Check that forecasts and test data match

Comment: Hi Yan! Is it possible to share a reproducible example? Also, would you mind add more details about the package you are using which make it easier to find reference.

Answer (score 0):

There is varresult inside of your model Var_model, so you see different accuracy metrics and define how good your model on training set like
`accuracy(your_model_name$varresult$col_name)`

Also you should check decomposition waives for seasonal period and lags correlation and cross-correlation and if you using VAR because all variable will impacting each other on forecast level.